# How to colour a column differently depending on value

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex, lov

I am trying to create a column in a report which would take entries from a corresponding column from the database. This LOV is returning the `active` or `inactive` status depending on the value of the base column.

I would like to add colours to this column so it could be easier to spot records where the status has been set to `inactive`. So, green for `active` and red for `inactive`.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IR region source

```
select * from emp
```

Made an LOV on deptno
[image: LOV on column deptno]

Run the report. Go to Actions > Format > Highlight
[image: actions format highlight]

On the highlight options you can specify colours, whether to highlight the row or just a cell, and the condition for the highlight. Note that for lov columns you can pop open an lov with the values for that lov through the arrow button next to the expression field!
[image: highlighting options]

Applying this will result in this:
[image: highlighting results]

If you want this applied by default do not forget to save your report!

---

If highlighting is not to your satisfaction, you can still go the javascript / CSS way.

Create a dynamic action to fire after refresh of the IR region, with a true action of type Execute Javascript.

```
$("#apexir_DATA_PANEL td[headers='DEPTNO']").each(
function(){
   if($(this).text()=='ACCOUNTING'){
      $(this).addClass('deptAccounting'); //great to keep style in CSS! 
      $(this).css({"background-color":"red"}); //for that quick fix
   }
}
);
```

Note that for this you need to specify the column (headers) and have to code in the to-be-compared text!

Comment: Thank you for extensive answer. However, is this only possible for interactive or is there a work around in "standard" report ??

Comment: The highlight is indeed only in interactive reports. You can use javascript in the classic reports though. The syntax is the same, you'll have to change the selector for the table though.